# Changing between landscape and portrait views in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, orientation

I am working on a JQuery Mobile app. My app will have different views of the same data depending on whether the device is in landscape or portrait view. Currently, I am detecting that change using the following code:

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange", function (e, ui) {
  alert("orientation changed: " + e.orientation);
});
```

From here, I'm not sure where to go. I would like to change views. However, I don't want to reload the view as I want it to be as fast as possible. How do I show different views based on the orientation? What does that HTML look like? I know that a single view is defined like this:

```
<div id="myPage" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home">Back</a>
    <h1>My App</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <!-- Page content goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a multi-page layout, with one page having the portrait view and the other having the landscape view, then call `$.changePage()` to switch between them on the `orientationChange` event.